# Bypass ngrok using a proxy

Tags: proxy, ngrok

In order to improve DX, I'm trying to locally redirect ngrok request to localhost:3000 without going to ngrok servers

I need ngrok to embed my app in shopify admin but other than that, I want the requests to go directly to localhost and thus make reloading and hmr much faster

Is there a way to do this using a proxy?
Is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve exactly this via the following:

1. Set up nginx locally.
2. Create server configurations for each subdomain; for example:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       listen 443 ssl;
       server_name example.ngrok.io;

       ssl_certificate     /usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/self-signed.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/ssl/private/self-signed.key;

       ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
       ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
       ssl_dhparam /usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a self-signed certificate locally for wildcards (I use multiple ngrok tunnels) following [this tutorial](https://blog.cpming.top/p/create-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx). Note I changed all instances of "test.cpming.top" to "*.ngrok.io". Also note that I used "2048" instead of "128" for the `openssl dhparam` command.
4. Add the tunnel subdomains to /etc/hosts pointing them to 127.0.0.1; for example: `127.0.0.1 example.ngrok.io`.

Please note you will need to temporarily disable this by commenting out entries you added in `/etc/hosts` in order to install the app via OAuth with Shopify.

Things load **MUCH** faster now in development mode. This also lets me work in coffee shops with lower bandwidth wifi connections, and I use much less bandwidth if I tether to my phone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, this makes developing much faster and easier

Comment: @unloco I made a change to how `prefix` is defined. I was getting an infinite loop in production, and setting it to `''` solves this.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version of `@shopify/koa-shopify-auth` and have updated instructions to NOT include the `prefix` parameter as it was preventing installs. The `prefix` parameter should be a path that does not include a domain. See [this line](https://github.com/Shopify/koa-shopify-auth/blob/master/src/auth/index.ts#L61).